# PHP / Ajax code not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out why this isn't working! The idea is the code is supposed to run a php script on another page that will check for changes in the DB state. Then it will return a string that will update the CURRENT page.

(External) PHP:

```
$QgetShift = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shifts");

$num = mysql_num_rows($QgetShift);

if(isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['data'])) {

        $data = $_SESSION['data'];      
        if($data != $num){
            $_SESSION['data'] = $num;
            echo "WORKING";
        } else {
            echo "NOT WORKING";
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['data'] = $num;
        echo "started";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="clickMe">Click Here</button> <br />
                <div id="data"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'function.php',
    data: {
      'ajax': true
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#data').text(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me if there is an error somewhere?

Comment: By not working, do you mean that you're getting an output of "NOT WORKING", or that the script is failing to run?

Comment: You need to use "GET", not "POST".

Comment: @Trendy There's nothing wrong with using POST here.

Comment: May be `session_start()` could be a problem you have to put this on the top of the file

Comment: For one thing, you success function is changing a DIV. It should read: `$('#data').html(data);`

Comment: @dianuj it's there, sorry forgot to include that

Comment: @gibberish yes I'm going to try that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I'm dumb, the link was wrong :/

Comment: If any of the answers helped you to find the solution yourself, please upvote and select a correct answer. Otherwise, after the waiting period, please select your own answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This line in your AJAX success function is incorrect (`$('#data').text(data);`):  Try instead:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#data').html(data);
}
```

Another thing to try is to add this to the top of your function.php file (just for one test):

```
<?php
    echo 'Received OK from PHP';
    die();
```

Comment: Weird... it's not pulling in that string. Any ideas?